# How to get images selected in the image picker that I choose earlier?

Tags: angular, image, ionic4

I am trying to show the selected images that I selected previously in ionic image picker. As once I close the image picker I cannot mark the images that I selected earlier.

I have gone through documentation but couldn't found any of the options

```
  this.imagePicker.getPictures({
      maximumImagesCount: 10
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare in the export Class :
`images :any[]=[];`

and then in your function you have to write this :

```
 getPhoto(){
    let options : ImagePickerOptions ={
      maximumImagesCount: 5, // number of pictures 
      quality:70,  // quality 70/100
      width: 512,  // optional
      height: 256, // optional
      outputType: 1 // type of output 1 if you want to use base64 or 0 for file_uri type

  };
    return this.imagePicker.getPictures(options).then( (res)=>{
      for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        let nrm = `data:image/jpeg;base64,`+res[i];
        this.images.push(nrm); // this will push the links of pictures from your device to the array images 
    }
    })
  }
```

and then you can display it with ngfor in your html

Comment: Nah I want to show it again in the gallery as well. while selected more pictures